# JPA entity model best practices

Tags: java, jpa, weblogic, eclipselink

We try to figure out a memory leak and right now we are at a point where we think about the size of the entity model and relations between entities. We are using EclipseLink 2.0.2 as JPA provider running in WebLogic 10.3.3.

Our model consists of 162 entities. Those are not all directly connected to each other but you can navigate from one starting entity to an arbitrary other entity through transitive relations. All associations except one-to-one are lazily loaded.

So, what was your biggest entity model and did you consider any memory leak or other wired behavior? Do you have any recommendations for designing an entity model? Are there common patterns you experienced to cause problems?

Comment: Your question is too broad. 162 is not a small number, and it's not a very large one either. Design your model in the most natural way, and make sure that most of the associations are lazy, to avoid loading half of the database which in every transaction.

Comment: Does the memory consumption increase over time, or it is "just" too high? Does number of entities in EntityManager increase over time?

Comment: PermGen consumption increases over time. How to find out how many entities are managed by the entity manager. As we are using container managed persistence I assume the em to be cleared after each call.

Comment: Have you done a heap analysis to see what types and number of objects are in the heap?  I would suggest using JRockit JVM with Mission Control.  Mission Control will let you see a great deal of information (similar to, but better than jvisualvm)

Answer (score 0):

What is the error that you get when you run out of memory, is it the heap or perm?  Have you tried increasing the heap or perm size?

How long does it take to run out of memory?

How have you configured caching, have you tried to disable the cache (shared=false) to determine if this is related to your memory issue.

Are you holding onto references to your domain objects in your application across requests, or through statics.  Do you have long lived EntityManagers.

Normally the best way to debug a memory issue is to use a memory profiler, such as JProfiler.

Comment: jvisualvm (which is included with Oracle JVMs from 1.6 onward) is also useful for exploring memory issues - and you probably already have it.

Comment: actually we use both ;-). It turned out we don't that perm gen consumption increases over time but a gc frees occupied space if perm gen is full. Good questions I will figure out more details during the next days.